# .NET MVC 4 routing with same number of parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, razor, routes

I have a controller named Admin which has two actions:
posts - this one takes a get parameter named screen
editpost - this one receives a get parameter named id

Now I want to route calls such as:
Admin/posts?screen=1 to be Admin/posts/1
and Admin/editpost?id=3 to be Admin/editpost/3

Both the parameters are integers, so adding constrains to the routes is useless(from what I tried).
I have tried this in my RouteConfig.cs and it fails:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Post pagination",
          url: "Admin/{screen}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Posts" }
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "EditPost",
        url: "Admin/EditPost/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "EditPost" }
    );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Another question is:
How can I get the controller and action name from the RouteConfig.cs file so I can make a general routing rule for pagination?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a standard redirect. This is best handled directly by IIS. However, if you want to do with MVC, you just need to add something like:

```
public ActionResult Posts(int id)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Posts", "Admin", new { id = id });
    }

    ...
}
```

That's not very elegant though, so I'd still recommend handling with the URL Rewrite Module in IIS.